# How to exit webpack-dev-server execution after running test suite

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, web-deployment, webpack-dev-server

I've created a webpack configuration file that builds the app, runs a dev server using webpack-dev-server and runs the test suite as below.

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  port: 3000,
  watchOptions: {
    open: false
  },
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: "/"
  }
},

plugins: [
  new WebpackShellPlugin({
    onBuildEnd: [`./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ${testScope}`]
  })
]
```

The command to start the whole thing is below

```
webpack-dev-server --config webpack.test.js
```

Everything is ok, but... what now? It never stops! I need some way to exit with a successful status when the test suite is ok. Otherwise, it would cause an infinite deploy (I use bitbucket pipelines to deploy the app).

Does someone know a way to exit the devServer execution after running a specific plugin?

Comment: What OS are you on? What application are you using to run the command, what command are you running, `npm run start` or `npm start`?

Answer (score 2):

Likely it is the difference between `npm run start` and `npm start`

When you use [`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html), it runs `node server.js` which doesn't run inline with your console.

If you use [`npm run start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), it executes the `start` script defined in your package.json using the shell of your operating system. Therefore, even if you are using Cygwin (or similar), it should still run it using cmd.exe.

**Solution**
Use `npm run start` instead of `npm start` and it should kill the process when you CTRL + C

Comment: I dont think you understood, so I edited the question to make it clearer. The same configuration file run the devserver and runs the test suite (as a plugin). What I need is to abort the devserver after the plugins executed. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It's easy for me to `CTRL + C`, but I need the process to finish by itself, so it would work when I run this command in a deployment routine

Comment: Got it. Yes, your edit makes much more sense. Thanks for sharing your answer too!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem by creating a webpack plugin and added it to my config file. The plugin code is below. It runs the command I pass to it and exit the process, firing error if the command was successful or success if it was everything ok.

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

module.exports = class RunScriptAndExit {
  constructor(command) {
    this.command = command;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin("after-emit", (compilation, callback) => {
      const { command, args } = this.serializeScript(this.command);
      const proc = spawn(command, args, { stdio: "inherit" });
      proc.on("close", this.exit);

      callback();
    });
  }

  serializeScript(script) {
    if (typeof script === "string") {
      const [command, ...args] = script.split(" ");
      return { command, args };
    }
    const { command, args } = script;
    return { command, args };
  }

  exit(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
      process.exit(1);
    } else {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }
};
```

I added it to my plugin list as below:

```
plugins: [
  new RunScriptAndExit(`./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ${testScope}`)
]
```